# JS Win 8 desktop app message boxes

Tags: javascript, windows, desktop

If I plug-in an usb device to my desktop pc running windows 8 a message box shows up.
Any chance to use this type of message box from within my JS desktop app? Any code snippets available? Or can I use it from within a dos batch file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript app? Windows 8 Store App?

Comment: "Desktop app", sorry. My answer was about web apps. I deleted it, anyway this is what it was about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification